# Is form data cached?

Tags: forms, caching

Is form date cached? I have an interesting bug on my site. There is a form for logged in users and it is used very frequently. Sometimes, after long time usage, some data doesn't change when it should (another node..). It looks like it is cached.

How can i disable this "form cache" or force form on creation to load new data, not cached (old)?

thanks

Comment: It's Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: It's drupal 7 ..

Comment: Maybe `$form_state['no_cache'] = TRUE;` helps?
more here - http://drupal.org/node/689084

Comment: Thanks, i will try. The problem is that it is really difficult to reproduce the error.

Comment: It turns out that it doesn't solve it. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: these 'some data' has related to some entities and you have entity_cache module?

Comment: Are you logged in when that happens? Is the anonymous page cache enabled?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Drupal doesn't cache submitted form data. However, generated HTML Code is cached in many places.

I've come upon this problem when rendering a form in a block produced by a custom module. If block caching is active and the form is sometimes rendered with some fields pre-filled (The user's name, the previously used search term), that version of the form might be cached and displayed to other users.
This particular case is easily fixed by setting `$block['my_block']['cache'] = DRUPAL_NO_CACHE;` in your module's implementation of `hook_block_info`.